# Is it possible use a non-object shapeless.Poly1 that works with Everywhere?

Tags: scala, shapeless

My attempt below doesn't work:

```scala
class Absolute(rootDir: File) extends Poly1 {
  implicit def caseFile[F <: File]: Case[F] { type Result = File } = at[F] { f =>
    if (f.isAbsolute)
      f
    else
      val parts =
        file.getPath.split(Pattern.quote(File.separator)).toList.filterNot(Set("", "."))
      parts match {
        case ":root-dir" :: tail => tail.foldLeft(rootDir)(new File(_, _))
        case ":home" :: tail => tail.foldLeft(new File(sys.props("user.home")))(new File(_, _))
        case _ => f
      }
  }
}

object Absolutised {
  def from(rootDir: File) = new Runner(new Absolute(rootDir))

  final class Runner(absolute: Absolute) {
    def apply[T](t: T)(implicit everywhere: Everywhere[absolute.type, T]) = everywhere(t)
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you seen [this thread](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/shapeless-dev/P5DXRgnzqkY/E76joeGZyqAJ)?

Comment: No I failed at finding that. Thanks Travis.

Comment: Sorry it's not better news… :(

Answer (score 1):

Not ideal, but there's a workaround working in scala 2.11.8 with shapeless 2.3.0:

```scala
object Absolutised {
  def from(rootDir: File) = new Runner(rootDir)

  final class Runner(rootDir: File) {

    object ab2 extends Absolute(rootDir)

    def apply[T](t: T)(implicit everywhere: Everywhere[ab2.type, T]) = everywhere(t)
  }
}
```

Comment: And you can avoid `Case[F] { type Result = File }` with `Case.Aux[F, File]`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work :-/ I'll have to do some more investigation, see if I can figure out why not..

Comment: That's weird... do you have some collection type other than `List` in your case class?

Comment: And try adding a `println` at the beginning of the function body to simply check where it's actually called or not.